# How do change the default directory for file creation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-handling

i have been using visual studio for programming and i want to change the default directory when i create a new file of any type with c++. However , is there a way where i can specify where a file should be placed in my project.
for eg:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main() {


    ofstream file;  
    file.open("shader.txt");


    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

when i create this file it is created in the project directory. How do i specify the  file path for where to create the file.

Comment: How do you create new files?

Comment: using the fstream header file

Comment: I think it depends from the current working directory. You can change it using `std::filesystem::current_path` (C++17).

Comment: Why not pass a full path to `file.open ()`?

Comment: can you give an example.